# Does releasing a new version remove existing version from appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app, but I would like to make some fixes. If I upload a new version, will it invalidate the existing app until it is approved? or the existing version will continue to be available on the appstore?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existing version will be available until the new one is approved, unless you invalidate it yourself.